# Nested div element not responding to onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to nest two divs inside each other. When you hover either div both the elements rotate and expand. When the nested div is no longer hovered over it stays expanded. When neither div is hovered over, both divs need to go back to the normal state.

Code I have causes the parent div to go back, but the nested div retains its size. Is there any way I can make both divs go back to their original state?

The HTML:

```
<div class="frames" id="frame1" onmouseout="document.getElementById('mini_frame').style.width='150px';.style.height='150px';"><div class="mini_frame" onmouseout="stay(this)">1</div></div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function stay(x) {
        x.style.width="300px";
        x.style.height="300px";
    }
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
.mini_frame {
    background-color:#faf5e6;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    top:10px;
    position:static;
    vertical-align:center;
}
.mini_frame:hover {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    transition:all 2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s linear 0s;
}
#frame1 {
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate:(-20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate:(-20deg);
    z-index:5;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    right:15px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
#frame1:hover {
    transition:all 2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s linear 0s;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate:(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate:(360deg);
    z-index:6;
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Comment: Could you give as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/37SCp/

Comment: That, koala_dev, is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much.